# Setting dynamic values for dropdown filters

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, .net, sql-server

I have a gridview and a dropdown filters in the page. Also I have a date column in gridview which has values like `2014-04-12` and `2014-04-25`. Assuming the current budget year if someone adds a row with the year 2016 and when I filter the dropdown I have exclude that 2016 columns using this below query.

**Query:**

```
select ID, Group,CONVERT(Date, Summary_Date) as Summary_Date from Application where  Group='" + selectedGroup + "' and Summary_Date <='2015-01-01' order by ID, Summary_Date
```

Now this query will work only for current budget year. And if we have moved to next budget year I have to exclude rows which has 2017 rows and how can I handle that dynamically. Anyone pls let me know for further clarity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DateAdd function instead of manual work.

If am not wrong, you can change your query like this,

```
select ID, Group,CONVERT(Date, Summary_Date) as Summary_Date from Application where  Group='" + selectedGroup + "' and Summary_Date <=Dateadd(year,1,getdate()) order by ID, Summary_Date
```

Here it will add automatically one year from your current year. For eg : in the case of 2014, query will filter the records within 2015. Same as 2016,2017 etc.,

For further clarification about DateAdd, please [Click Here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_dateadd.asp)

Comment: This worked and if I want to show values upto 2015-01-01 for current year and for 2015 I need to show values upto 2016-01-01. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I just take your scenario like this, you want your result up to 2016 from 2015 right ?. If so this query is right. If 2015 year comes, this query will leave you the records till 2016. You don't need to change anything. Please let me know if you face with any confusions.

Comment: Let me be clear. For this year if I do the filters I should be able to see all values of 2014 and 2015 values upto 2015-01-01. And we move to 2015 year I should be able to see all 2015 values and values upto 2016-01-01 and so on. Pls let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Just consider am having two 2 records in the year period 2014 - 2015, and 3 records in the year period 2015 - 2016. Now am in the year of 2014. So when i execute the above query, it will leave only two records. And when the year 2015 arrived, it will leave three records. Am i clear ?. To be short the above query is right for your condition. You just use it, you will get your expected result in the year of 2015 also.

Comment: Okay. I have 2 records for 2015 like 2015-01-01 and 2015-03-05. Now we are in 2014 year and when I filter I should see all 2014 values and for 2015 I should see only 2015-01-01 and I shouldn't see 2015-03-05 and it has go on for coming years.

Comment: No, It will filter 2015-03-05 also. Because the above query tells you clearly that, get the record from today date to next year. It mean today date is 2014-04-29 right?, so it will filter the records till the 2015-04-29. To end with beginning of the year. You need to change your query like this, Summary_Date <=DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,getdate()) + 1, 0). Try this and let me know the result.

Comment: That worked amnd this will work for forcoming years too right.

Comment: Could you happen to have an answer for my query?

Comment: Sorry i couldn't get you. Did you ask any query ?

Comment: Yes I was asking whether this work for forcoming years too or should I have to make any changes in the future.

Comment: No need. It will work. If you have any doubts, you just change your system time and check it whether you're getting or not..!